# What is the negation of the statement $f=0$ almost everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory, logic

Today in class, we were proving a theorem that relied on negating the statement $f=0$ almost everywhere, for $f$ a function.

However, I am not convinced of the right negation. What is it?

Comment: The negation of almost everywhere is somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$\;f=0\;$ almost everywhere is false" = there exists a set $\;E\;$ of positive measure s.t. $\;f(x)\neq 0\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in E\;$

Comment: I assumed all the time $\;f\;$ is measurable and then $\;\{x\;:\;\;f(x)\neq 0\}\;$ is a measurable set. And yes: it can be done wider as you explain, @leo. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm...a doubt that came to me now: isn't a function $\;f=0\;a.e.\;$ measurable?

Answer (score 2):

The negation of $\mu \{ x : f(x) \ne 0 \} = 0$ is $\mu \{ x : f(x) \ne 0 \} \ne 0$.